# jquery $.when(ajax).always() fires after OPTIONS

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my code I use $.when(ajax1, ajax2, etc).always() to run a couple of Ajax and i want something to happen after they was executed.

I noticed that the always() function is already executed when the OPTIONS pre-flight requests are returned and not when the PUT/POST request are returned. That's strange in my opinion and I also didn't find anything on the net regarding this behavior. How could i set up $.when to wait for my POST/PUT and not the OPTIONS?

Comment: Doesn't always mean _always_?

Comment: Yes always after the ajax have been returned but I would expect that only always after my intended ajax has returned which means my put/post request. It doesn't help me when it executes after the pre-flight options request

Comment: How do you know this is what's happening?

Comment: $.when(a1,a2).always(function(r1,r2){console.log(r1)}) and r1 is undefined My successful post would however contain the created record in the body

Comment: I believe also in the always it contains the data because when i give a get-request as a1 then i will have data in r1

Comment: preflight success is not a trigger for  completed request. Browser is the owner of the preflight and knows full well what it is for

Answer (score 0):

Okay $.when does not fire on options pre-flight. What happened was that they already started executing right before i gave them to $.when which was my bad because i missed to use the return-statement as in "return $.ajax"